ansible shell module execute timeout apt install command stuck
then there is a playbook pl.yaml
- name: say 'hello world'
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: run command
      shell: "timeout 100 apt install mysql-client -y"
      args:
        chdir: "/root"
      register: output

    - name: debug_output
      debug:
        var: output.stdout_lines


I run the script a.sh by a playbook
then I run command ansible-playbook  pl.yaml -i inventory -f 5 -b.
the process will get stuck in apt command.
strace the apt install mysql-client -y process, I can see stop by SIGTTOU.
(although the process stuck, but found the mysql command had been installed)
If I remove timeout shell command and apt install mysql-client -y will be ok.
If I modify command to timeout 100 echo | apt install mysql-client -y Or I add 'timeout --foreground 100'. it also will be ok.
If I login the target server, and execute any above commands directly, all of commands will be ok .
Why ansible shell module execute will get stuck and why there is no problem logging into server to execute command directly ?

but bottomline, why not use apt or package ansible module

I could reproduce your issue using ansible ad-hoc command, the fix was adding --foreground key to timeout command:

 --foreground
            when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
              allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals;
              in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out


The resulting command was
ansible -b -i inventory.ini -m "shell" -a "timeout --foreground 100 apt install mysql-client -y" my_server

Apt is not meant for scripting, and possibly expects having a working TTY to handle it's inner workings. You should most certainly use package module to install software on machines, if they do not require package-manager specific setting (you should use apt module in this case)

Thanks for your response! My situation cannot control script content, and need timeout to control the script time in target server. Maybe will use --foreground to solve this problem.
This problem maybe related TTY, no-shell, signal , I really want to get some knowledge about these. Thanks again.
